# How do I `save()` a Profile model if it has a OneToOne relationship to my AbstractBaseUser model without running into UNIQUE constraint errors?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two separate models:
 1. A `MyUser` model which inherits from `AbstractBaseUser`, and has a field of `profile_page = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True)`
 2. A `Profile` model with a `user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)` relationship to the User model.

I am attempting to allow users of the site to edit their own `Profile` information by providing them a `ProfileForm` ModelForm.
In my user_profile/views.py I have this `profile_edit` FBV:

```
def profile_edit(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.instance.save()

        return redirect('/profile/edit')
else:
    form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    print(request.user)
    print('hello get req here')

context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', context)
```

When I attempt to update profile information in `profile_edit.html`, the POST data will go through the first time, but not get saved to the DB. On a second attempt, I receive a `UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_profile.user_id` error.
`form.instance.save()` is pointed to as the direct cause of the exception.

In my estimation the error has something to do with the fact that upon creation of a new user, an initial unique ID is created for the user. So when I try to save() the Profile object, I think it is attempting to save() a new User, thereby causing the Unique Constraint failure.

How can I configure the two models in such a way that upon creation of a new User, the User has the ability to update their own Profile information? What should change in my views.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong, both to do with the `instance` argument.

Firstly, in the GET block, you're passing `request.user` as the instance. But this is a Profile form; you need to pass the user profile, not the user itself:

```
form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
```

Secondly, in the POST block, you're not passing an instance at all. This means that Django won't know to update an existing item, but will try and create a new one. Again you need to pass the profile:

```
form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
```

Note also though, you should consider whether you need a separate Profile model at all. Initially that was the recommended way to provide custom user information, but for several versions Django has given you a way to use a customised User model - which you are in fact doing. You probably want to put the profile data directly in MyUser, rather than in a separate model with a one-to-one relationship.

**Edit after comment** It sounds like you're not automatically creating a profile when you create the user. You could do something like this in the view:

```
def profile_edit(request):
    try:
        profile = request.user.profile
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = Profile(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    ...
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

Comment: I've made the changes, and it allows me to update/save profile information, but when I attempt to register a new user and try it again, I receive a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/edit/` `MyUser has no profile.` and it points to the edited code: `form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile) `  
What might be going on?

Comment: I would still separate the `User` and `Profile` models to keep from creating a god object. Try to do normalization where possible.